# BottomNavigationBar index error (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm having an app with a bottom navigation bar:

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print("current tab");
    print(currentTab?.index); //<-- It's work!! -->

    return BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: _colorTabMatching(currentTab!),
        selectedFontSize: 13,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: currentTab?.index, //<-- does not work!! -->
        items: [
          _buildItem(TabItem.POSTS),
          _buildItem(TabItem.ALBUMS),
          _buildItem(TabItem.TODOS),
        ],
        onTap: (int index) => onSelectTab!(
            TabItem.values[index]
        )
    );
```

Error:

> The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

Now I need to pass the index, but I see an error. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentIndex` doesn't take nullable int.

Doing `currentTab?.index` means it is accepting null value. You can provide default value as 0 on null case like,

```dart
currentIndex: currentTab?.index?? 0
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) and [currentIndex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar/currentIndex.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming from C# background, and judging only by the error message, basically what is happening is, property `currentIndex` is supposed to be of type `int`. Problem with your code is that `currentTab` is of type `TabItem?` meaning nullable TabItem. Meaning it can be either `null` or `TabItem object`. Using the syntax `currentTab?.index` is basically saying: "If currentTab is null, just return null. If it is not null, then return me the index value.". Dart syntax is very similar to C#'s, and I checked that this code will work:

```
currentIndex: currentTab?.index ?? 0
```

Basically what this code does, is: "If currentTab is null, then return the value 0. If it is not null, then return me the index value.". See the difference? You basically have to manually handle the situation where the `currentTab` is equal to `null`.

Disclaimer: I did not try this code, however as I said, C# and Dart are similar (as far as syntax goes), and I double checked on the internet that Dart does offer these syntax features

Edit: Or you can handle currentTab being null using some Flutter way, before rendering, however, as I said before, I don't know Dart/Flutter.